# Get several JSON files in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, jsonp

The structure of JSON link is as follows:

> www.something.com/link-**number**-rest-of-the-link.com.json

Now I need to get several JSON link files and the only thing that changes is the **number** part in the link above. Let's say it ranges from 10 to 40, so the first one looks like this:

> www.something.com/link-**10**-rest-of-the-link.json

and the second one looks like this

> www.something.com/link-**11**-rest-of-the-link.com.json

and so on until it reaches number 40.

Is there a way I can get it all in one function. I've tried this:

```
var nmr = function({for(nmr=10;nmr<40;nmr++)});

var json = 'www.something.com/link'+nmr+'rest-of-the-link.json';
```

but it won't work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

*Please note that I have't put the "http" part as the SO automatically links it.*

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can aggregate the result of multiple calls in one object : for each number of the given range, do the call and add the response in an array which you'll return

Comment: how do you magically get json directly from the urls?

Comment: Please provide with the sample. Thanks.

Comment: @madalin, edited.

Comment: `but it won't work.` what does this mean?

Comment: I'm not getting anything. Not even an error.

Comment: @tholo what did you edit, where is your ajax request?

Comment: ajax request is irrelevant at this point. What I want to know is if I can iterate the 'dynamic' part like this.

Comment: what does the code  `var nmr = function({for(nmr=10;nmr<40;nmr++)});` do ? what is the value of nmr , what kind of  loop is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can build array like this

```
var links = [];
for(var i=2005;i<2015.length;i++){
  links.push('http://www.link.com/an-'+i+'-rest');
}
//now make your request for each link
```

another example

```
var requested = 0;
  function startLoading(){
    if(requested==2015) {
      return alert("all files loaded");
    }
    makeRequest('http://www.link.com/an-'+requested+'-rest');
  }

  function makeRequest(url){
    //the body of request
    //then
    //if response is ready make what you want for it and go next
    requested++;
    startLoading();
    // and startLoading(); to go to the next link
  }

  startLoading(); //start
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
var json = [];
for(var i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
   json.push('www.something.com/link-'+i+'-rest-of-the-link.json');
}
```

Now `json` would have all links from 10 to 40. If you want to get the content, use `ajax` to do that

Answer (score 0):

**concepts**

- generate array of promises that will call each json file from url
- execute each promise in the same time

**sample**

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const rp = require('request-promise')

function getJsonFromUrlParam(num) {
  const uri = `www.something.com/link-${num}-rest-of-the-link.json`

  return rp({ method: 'GET', uri, json: true })
}

/** declare param */
const params = []

for (let i = 10; i <= 40; i++) {
  /** get each promise param */
  params.push(getJsonFromUrlParam(i))
}

/** get each json file in the same time */
Promise.all(params)
  .then(result => {
    /** get result here 
     * result is array of json files
     */
     console.log(result)
  })
```

Comment: how can we do this in v1 ?